# Mourning for only certain relatives?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, non-religious

After learning the Rambam ([Mourning 1:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Mourning.1.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> וְכֵן הָאֶפִּיקוֹרוֹסִין [וְהַמּוּמָרִים] וְהַמּוֹסְרִין כָּל אֵלּוּ
>   אֵין מִתְאַבְּלִין עֲלֵיהֶן

it seems that we don't mourn for these categories of Jews. Are there other Poskim who disagree with the Rambam?

Comment: Rambam is basing himself on Masekhet Semachot 2:10. (Hard to imagine someone disputing it.)